# Como capturar os cookies do site salvos no navegador?

Tags: php, libcurl

Oi, pessoal. Como eu faço para capturar os cookies de um site e passar para o curl? Eu estou usando a extensão "cookie editor" para ver os cookies e passando para um arquivo txt  para rodar no curl, mas eu não consigo ver a pagina eu desejo, alguém poderia ajudar?

"porque vc não tenta fazer o login através do curl?"

Eu já tentei mas eu acho que eles usam alguma função do JavaScript que impede o login com curl.

```
     libxml_use_internal_errors(true) and libxml_clear_errors();
     $header = "X-Forwarded-For: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}";

     $url_login = "https://extra.bet365.com/results";

     $chl = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookies.txt');
     curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_login);
     curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
     curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
     curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
     curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
     curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
     curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
     curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
     curl_setopt($chl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
     $error = curl_error($chl);
     $dado = curl_exec($chl); 
     curl_close ($chl);


      echo $dado;
```

Comment: Vai contar cartas?

Comment: Não é possível você pegar os cookies de um site que tem o dominio diferente do seu... Por exemplo se o cookie é do site bet365.com só essa url consegue ler os cookies que ele deixou.